# Optional (numeric) attributes without default value in Core Data - why are they discouraged?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, null

The [Apple Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW6) says:

> You can specify that an attribute is optional—that is, it is not
>   required to have a value. In general, however, you are discouraged
>   from doing so—especially for numeric values (typically you can get
>   better results using a mandatory attribute with a default value—in the
>   model—of 0). The reason for this is that SQL has special comparison
>   behavior for NULL that is unlike Objective-C's nil. NULL in a database
>   is not the same as 0, and searches for 0 will not match columns with
>   NULL.

But i need my attributes to have no value at all (nil) when they are created. I cannot have `0` (Zero) or any other default value, because that would result in wrong domain data.

So what problems will arise if i define my numeric Core Data attributes as optional with no default value? And can i live with them?

Comment: Just my 2 cents, for my job, I have to deal a lot with data from other industry, and just so often the data is missing, and we have to live with that. So that's what NULL for, it means that there is no data. And I also think that's what the book talking about, NULL is different from zero. And yes, you can live with it, knowing the difference between zero and NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have a numeric (`int` for example) optional column in your DB. If you leave it blank, there will be a NULL in the DB. Now say you subclass `NSManagedObject` and use primitive types in your object. That column will be mapped to an `int` property. When the object is loaded, what will it put in there? It can't be `nil` and it can't be zero.

It's discouraged, not forbidden. Just don't use primitive types in your model objects, which from what you are saying, you wouldn't use in this case anyway if you need to be able to support nils.

Comment: Ok. I must investigate what real types in the model objects the Core Data attribute types are translated to. I have naively hoped, it would be NSNumbers — but perhaps they are really primitive C types.

Comment: You have both options. There's a checkbox in the "subclass NSManagedOject" dialog to pick which one you want. I think by default it's NSNumber, but the point is they discourage it just to avoid the problem in case you do pick a primitive. So just don't pick primitives and you'll be fine with optional columns.

Comment: I guess in swift it doesn't really matter, since both `NSNumber` and `Int` can be optionals and therefore be set to `nil` (although I think technically, `Int` et al. are not primitive types, on the same footing as those in C/Objective-C; perhaps they are `struct`s internally?).